# How can I return line by line like iteraction for a variable and takes values starting line1, and stops when the length of my file ends?

Tags: python

I have this file (pruebe.txt), and has this information:

```
(1, 1)
(15, 20)
(13, 21)
(4, 3)
(2, 26)
```

I need to do this:

1.- Read line by line the elements (a, b) like a string in the function and then, return other line, and so that, stop when the length of my file ends.

MY CODE is:

```
class function(loop):
    def re_loops(l,foo=2):
        out = []
        last = l[0]
        for x in l:
            if x-last > foo:
                yield out
                out = []
                out.append(x)
                last = x
                c=[int(e) for e in last]
                a, b = c
                yield out
                return

   # This routine picks the results to be refined by loop 

def select_loop(self):
    with open('list.log') as f:
        # insertion 
            return selection(self.residue_range(a, b)
```

I want something like this:

(a, b) = (1, 1) line 1

sustitute the values in line of my fuction:

return selection(self.residue_range(a, b)
give the result

and then return the line 2 with the values (a, b) = (15, 20) 
give the result

and stop when the length of my file = 0

What Can I change in my CODE for this task?
Can somebody help me plis

Comment: Are you already aware that you can iterate over the lines in a file much like you can iterate over a list/array? Is that what you'd like to see an example of?

Comment: Yes, but I dont have idea how do it. I've seen some examples and dont run it with my CODE. I would like to see my mistake about this. Do you know some module, class, or some, that can to help me?

Comment: Sure... posted. Happy to update that to address specific areas of difficulty.

Comment: @dylrei I did the code to read line to line, but read all the lines in the same time. I need read a one line (for example, line 1) and the run the function, finally, return the line 2, and do the process again, so end the lenght to file that has each value (pruebe.txt). What Can I do it?

Comment: In pruebe.txt, the second line with `(15, 20)` what is `15` and what is `20`? And what do you want to do with these?

Comment: Yes, the second line is (15, 20), I want this: When the code finish to process the function with the values of the line 1 (1, 1), selec the best score, and star again the code but this time, with the values of the line 2, and stop when the lenght (lines) of the file pruebe.txt ends.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a high-level sketch of a typical line-by-line process in Python:

```
with open('file_path', 'r') as f, open('logfile.txt', 'w') as logfile:
    for line in f:
        # process each line here
```

Under this approach, you'll process each line in order and processing will stop (and the file will be closed) after the last line is processed.

**Update**: providing a bit more help...

```
import ast
with open('file_path', 'r') as f, open('logfile.txt', 'w') as logfile:
    for line in f:
        # easy/clean way to extract x and y vals
        x, y = ast.literal_eval(line.strip())

        # easy way to find larger of x or y
        largest = max([x, y])

        # write out larger score to log
        logfile.writeline(largest + '\n')

        # and honestly, I'm not sure what else you're doing with each line
```

Comment: I did the code to read line to line, but read all the lines in the same time. I need read a one line (for example, line 1) and the run the function, finally, return the line 2, and do the process again, so end the lenght to file that has each value (pruebe.txt). What Can I do it?

Comment: The code above *does* process the file line-by-line. I also updated the code to show how you might handle an input and output file at the same time.

Comment: @TereHs Added some additional help. I'm not sure I understand exactly what the goal of your code is, but if you wanted to rip through the x,y scores in one file and write them to another, this should do it.

Comment: @TereHs Honestly, I don't have the bandwidth to puzzle out what you're trying to do with your code. It's unlikely that you need more than ~10 lines, whatever it is. Try opening a Python interpreter session and typing in what I have. I think you might be surprised how easy your task probably is.

Comment: @TereHs: You should rather take a step back and pause and look at this code and understand what it does and implement it on your code. @dylrei opens two files simultaneously one input another output and read one line at a time from the input file, he then calls the function `ast.literal_eval()` to process the line and `max` to work with the processed data. This is where you need to call your function. Then he writes the result to the output file. Then proceed to the next line until the end of file. This is what you wanted.